# Access is denied message when opening an sharepoint list item form in modal dialog

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, infopath

I need to present an Infopath new Sharepoint list item form in a modal dialog. I've managed to display this form with some javascript and Content Editor Web Part, but after user clicks "Submit", there's "Access is denied" error on the page and the page/modal dialog does not close automatically.

Edit: (javascript code added)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = {
url: "http://myurl/NewForm.aspx",
        title: "New Event Log Entry",
        allowMaximize: true,
        showClose: true,
        width: 825,
        height: 525,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: silentCallback};
function open() {SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);}
function silentCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) {
}
function refreshCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) {
    SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Operation Successful!');
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
}</script>

<a href="javascript:open()"><img width="16" height="16" class="ms-asset-icon ms-rtePosition-4" src="/SiteAssets/Event%20Reporting.png" alt="" style="width: 40px; height: 40px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you double checked permissions? Not sure based on your question what kind of problem solving steps you've gone through but usually whenever I get an "Access Denied" error then it has to do with permissions.

Perhaps the users do not have permission to edit the list.

Comment: I don't think permissions on the list are the problem. When I go directly to the list view and add a new entry from there, everything works fine. I'm only having problems when I want to add new entry from another Sharepoint page (which is on another site collection and on different domain)